# google analytics not records my website visitors

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-analytics

i am using google analytics to track my visiters.
i am using below code but its not working for my website.but same code i have used in different website then it works
i have added code in head section

```
<script language="C#" runat="server">

        // Copyright 2010 Google Inc. All Rights Reserved.
        private const string GaAccount = "UA-xxxxxxx-1";
        private const string GaPixel = "ga.aspx";
        private string GoogleAnalyticsGetImageUrl()
        {
            System.Text.StringBuilder url = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
            url.Append(GaPixel + "?");
            url.Append("utmac=").Append(GaAccount);
            Random RandomClass = new Random();
            url.Append("&utmn=").Append(RandomClass.Next(0x7fffffff));
            string referer = "-";
            if (Request.UrlReferrer != null && "" != Request.UrlReferrer.ToString())
            {
                referer = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();
            }
            url.Append("&utmr=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(referer));
            if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url != null)
            {
                url.Append("&utmp=").Append(HttpUtility.UrlEncode(Request.Url.PathAndQuery));
            }
            url.Append("&guid=ON");
            return url.ToString().Replace("&", "&amp;");
        }

    </script>
```

also i have `ga.aspx` file on root folder.

But it doesn't work for my new website:

http://www.deltecs.com (google analytics not work in this website)
http://www.dronamobile.com (same code working for this website)

Comment: did the ga.aspx works correctly ? Do you have test it ?

Comment: how to test ga.aspx working or not

Comment: See first of all if you get an error on the log, then check inside ga.aspx what it do.

Comment: i am not getting any error on browser or in debugging mode.

Comment: The next you need to check is if the server permit to connect to `http://www.google-analytics.com/__utm.gif` because ga.aspx call that file.

Answer (score -1):

Why are You using image tag to fetch Your asp script that outputs GA code?
You should just write js code to Your webpage.

I assume it's some kind of "I disabled js in my browser"?

Comment: i dont know about it. admin give a code and i have just copy and paste it. so now give me code snippet (example) .